# Is there a way to automate datasources mapping in Power BI Gateway connection?

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am trying to automate the publishing of Power BI report to different workspaces that act like Dev, Test and Prod environments. Using Powershell commands, I am able to achieve this automation via Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount.

I am stuck at how to automate the datasources mapping to the servers under Gateway connection in Datasets tab (Settings).

Is there like a Powershell or Power BI REST API that I can use to automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propably your solution is here:

```
POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/datasets/{datasetId}/Default.BindToGateway
```

And in request body, you need to specify datasources:

```
{
  "gatewayObjectId": "1f69e798-5852-4fdd-ab01-33bb14b6e934",
  "datasourceObjectIds": [
    "dc2f2dac-e5e2-4c37-af76-2a0bc10f16cb",
    "3bfe5d33-ab7d-4d24-b0b5-e2bb8eb01cf5"
  ]
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/bindtogatewayingroup

Comment: That does help. Do you know how to do that in Powershell script? Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount and then Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -ContentType application/json -Url 'groups/{GrpGUID}/datasets/{DsGUID}/Default.BindToGateway' -Method Post -Body '{
  "gatewayObjectId": "GWGUID",
  "datasourceObjectIds": [
    "DSOGUID1",
    "DSOGUID2"
  ]
}'. Does this format look correct? I am getting 404 and Write error. Am I missing some perms? Thanks.

Comment: Check your GUID for Group and/or Dataset.
In your URL you should avoid curly brackets, but it looks ok. I cannot test this solution now on my side.

$Group ="8d33a6a9-db16-49bf-af74-6d018c49e177"
$dataset= "d40b8843-5bdf-4f58-9951-2ffd5bb0cc63"


$UrlGroup = "groups/$Group/datasets/$dataset/Default.BindToGateway"

Check info about permissions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/register-app